# Typescript generics: How to implicitly derive the type of a property of an object from another property of that object?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I want to type objects within an array, so that one property of the object (here `foo`) implicitly defines the type for another property (`bar`) for each object seperately.

Is that possible?

```
type Foo<T> = {
  foo: T;
  bar: T;
};

const foos: Foo<any>[] = [ // <-- What to put here instead of "any"?
  { foo: "text", bar: "this is ok"}, 
  { foo: 666, bar: "this is NOT ok" }, // <-- should show error (must be of type number)
];
```

In the example `foo` and `bar` have the same type, in my real case scenario I have:

```
type Column<TData, TValue> = {
  accessorFunction: (data:TData) => TValue,
  cell: (info:TValue) => any
}

const columns = [
  {
    accessorFunction: ()=> "test",
    cell: (info) => info   // <-- info should be of type string
]
```

But I guess this has the same typing problem.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "existential types" and they are not directly supported in typescript. There are a few different approachs to somehow encoding them in TS. [Here's one](https://www.jalo.website/existential-types-in-typescript-through-continuations)

Comment: Without existential types, you need some kind of workaround.  One way to proceed with arrays is to use a mapped tuple type and a helper function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5P05w).  Another is to emulate existential types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDyL8m), but that's probably overkill. Do either of those meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Note that for your `Column<D, V>` case, inference is harder.  I'd probably just use a single helper function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEPqgW).  I could write up this version if you care about `Column<D, V>` more than `Foo<T>`.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz: Thank you very much. I'd be glad to accept your `Column<D, V>` function as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm going to focus on your `Column` example and ignore `Foo`, because the inference issues are different, and you care about `Column` more than `Foo`).

Conceptually something like "a collection of objects, each of which is of type `Column<D, V>` for a particular `D` I know, but for some `V` I don't care about" requires [existentially quantified generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types). (I presume you need to know `D`, since, if you don't, there's no way to call `accessorFunction`).

But few languages support such types, and neither does TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) for the relevant feature request.  If we did have them, you could say something like `Array<Column<D, exists V>>`. But we don't, so we can't.

---

There are ways to encode existential types.  The *general* method to use a `Promise`-like data structure to invert control flow with [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) callbacks.  A generic function allows the caller to specify the type parameter while the implementer only knows that it's *some* type.  It looks like this:

```
type SomeColumn<D> = <R>(cb: <V>(col: Column<D, V>) => R) => R;
```

A `SomeColumn<D>` is like a `Promise<Column<D, ??>>`'s `then()` method.  It accepts a callback and then presumably calls the callback on the underlying `Column<D, V>` it's holding.  To turn a `Column<D, V>` into a `SomeColumn<D>`, we can use a helper function:

```
const someColumn = <D, V>(col: Column<D, V>): SomeColumn<D> => cb => cb(col);
```

Then your array could look like this:

```
const columns = [
    someColumn({
        accessorFunction: (a: string) => "test",
        cell: (info) => info.toUpperCase()
    }),
    someColumn({
        accessorFunction: (a: string) => a.length,
        cell: info => info.toFixed(2)
    })
];
```

That `columns` is of type `SomeColumn<string>`.  If we want to process the array, we have to add that one nested callback.  Say, like this:

```
const results = columns.map(
    sc => sc(
        col => col.cell(col.accessorFunction("hello"))
    )
)
// const results: any[]
console.log(results); // ["TEST", "5.00"]
```

Note that I'm doing just about the only useful thing I can do with a `Column<string, V>` where I don't know `V`... that is, calling `col.cell(col.accessorFunction(someString))`.  Anyway, `results` is an array of `cell()` outputs (which you've typed as `any`, so we have `any[]`).

---

That *might* be overkill for your use case.  Maybe all you care about is inference of the `cell()` method's input, and you don't mind if `columns` is an array like `Array<Column<string,string> | Column<string, number>>`.  If so, you can keep the helper function but just strip out any `Promise`-like behavior out of it.  It accepts a `Column<D, V>` and returns a `Column<D, V>`:

```
const column = <D, V>(col: Column<D, V>) => col;

const columns = [
    column({
        accessorFunction: (a: string) => "test",
        cell: (info) => info.toUpperCase()
    }),
    column({
        accessorFunction: (a: string) => a.length,
        cell: info => info.toFixed(2)
    })
]; // okay
```

But you will find it difficult to process these programmatically:

```
const results = columns.map(
    col => col.cell(col.accessorFunction("hello")) // error!
    // -----------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // compiler doesn't know that this will always be the right type for col.cell
);
```

There are workarounds there too, but they're annoying and you might as well just use a type assertion if you're careful to do so correctly:

```
const results = (columns as Array<Column<string, any>>).map(
  col => col.cell(col.accessorFunction("hello"))
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2AeAIgGigNQD4oBeKAbwCgoaoBDAYwYgGcW4AnAMSTQeACWcNAC4oACgAmdYHTFYAlKWL4c1WswQIx4gWgBmcMfiUlidNCEoBfSpTR0UrMI2gBRAB4CWwCGkF0CG58cJLQVOo0oJBQAMpwTvDI6NjEZBgASoTiDABGYhhEOYhiSaiYuASEpsQZNVAZANyRUAzCPlDsiYjlpFDYeEVt2rA9KZVECmLx3ckVacR5yq25xQgKzS1taB3D5Sx9ANottJ0JEGXo4lSnt7SMzGycPHyCwjpyncAcegDm9QAiXw+AFqO53TQjXQGOD1PSGAB0wDgAFUwJAODA6CwIOIFCdaNYFGDwV0LmM0NcCXcHqx2NxePwhKIJJ8fD80P9lnQEQg-L9gAALEngjQQLRieFwZZSpFwLgCDwQSTiABM+NFRJaAF1Nqdth0OKwkAhgAcyHt0CwESg6GBxNTOgxliwGA7RfrEMthgjIWsEbSngzXszxADBeKEHAAQoNeC4zQE1AAPTJ1rtYBQI0sE1msQWECHbVbdqICC8uC-cTZ3MsDYptOHAEAFTcsWboKgAIArAiAAx9gHFmx2BxOFguZhQABSSB8AEE0POOBw6CAKHZPTtM5a0H0BlU1qUKQfJt7EHqNBn03NzVBjqLd1SPfcmHTnoy3izxGzvn9AcCwCgo6+qRjoUpwjCcpohiWI4nijpEiKtxPjcL70G+QYvEy7ysmI7L-tyvL8kKyGPmBUBSjKUHIgqSoquqiFJrqDZQHAADWa6ble25Zsapp3ru1q2vajrDOeCC+pG-qBvS2FfmGEZaNGsasRAK6cAAhI6qZQAAtAZhlGXpxAAH7mRZllWdZNmmTpaZtCgYACHyHBQJIcCsGgADkmbsWgcAAO5QEKMghYK3hQIFLkIPQCCBWuBy5NAQrQD8vyCpm0TQIYbk+pCLQbNxNC6UgGVQLlvwQFlEUsC0+ifsyFVwHAhTZMMxhQBAHi+GgkgHAWUAAPyjHMGAEZygzEGIaAQAAbupShoXcRrAEgHB7vl0k+rJH4hsIimRipRWnLYW6GvxZqqn0Qk2na4iGK1E2-FAAA+UBoKgyUcNUzTnWWFZVjWAmMS0ukAFZzpmHnhZFFiSFAyXucI0DRUKlHACWvHA2aADMfRrPs9AHMuq4gBglyYM9eAFoQ1QIo6IlrBJUlaDJmFyY1B3hkdMaxps1hAA)

Answer (score 3):

This throws the intended error:

```
type Foo<T> = {
    foo: T;
    bar: T;
}

const foos: (Foo<string> | Foo<number> | Foo<boolean>)[] = [ // <-- What to put here instead of "any"?
    { foo: "text", bar: "this is ok" },
    { foo: 666, bar: 2323 }, // <-- should show error (must be of type number)
]
```

Unfortunately, this is not so easy to apply to your second example.
However, it is possible to force the manual specification of the type by enable "noImplicitAny" in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
type Column<TData, TValue> = {
    accessorFunction: (data: TData) => TValue,
    cell: (info: TValue) => any
}

const column: (Column<any, string> | Column<any, number> | Column<any, boolean>)[] = [
    {
        accessorFunction: () => "test",
        cell: (info) => info  // <-- if you enable "noImplicitAny" you get an error here because you need to define the type
    }
]
```