# How to type an object with a field in which each key can only be the the id property of an object in an array, with the array being another field?

Tags: typescript

### The question

How to type an object with a field in which each key can only be the the id property of an object in an array, with the array being another field? (using TypeScript)

The question might be a bit hard to understand first, so here's an example:

```js
const x = {
  fields: [
    {
      id: "field1",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      id: "field2",
      type: "number"
    },
    {
      id: "my_field",
      type: "email"
    }
  ],
  fieldValues: {
    field1: "John",
    field2: "John",
    my_field: "@"
  }
}
```

So the question is, how do I create a type for `x` so that `fieldValues` is checked if all keys are one of the `id`s in `fields`?

### My takes so far

#### Take #1

The following snippet works as expected, but each `id` requires the `as const` modifier, and the `fields` and `fieldValues` have to be defined separately.

```js
const fields = [
  {
    id: "bid" as const,
    c: "d"
  },
  {
    id: "cid" as const,
    c: "e"
  }
]

const fieldValues: Record<typeof fields[number]["id"], any> = {
  bid: "d",
  cid: "e",
  // The next line errors, yay!
  a: "f"
}
```

### Take #2

The following snippet is near perfect. However, Test requires defining the IDs explicitly, which is not desirable. The perfect solution would look like this, but without the need of providing those IDs explicitly.

```js
interface FieldType {
  type: "string" | "number" | "email"
}

type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> =
  ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never

type Fields<T extends string[]> = readonly (FieldType & {
  id: ArrayElement<T>
})[]

interface Test<T extends string[]> {
  fields: Fields<T>
  fieldValues: Record<ArrayElement<Fields<T>>["id"], any>
}

const x: Test<["field1", "field2", "my_field"]> = {
  fields: [
    {
      id: "field1",
      type: "string"
    },
    {
      id: "field2",
      type: "number"
    },
    {
      id: "my_field",
      type: "email"
    }
  ],
  fieldValues: {
    field1: "John",
    field2: "John",
    my_field: "@"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can define an interface of the `fieldValues` object, and then use the interface to provide typings for both the `fieldValues` object and the array elements.

Comment: There is no specific type that works that way; you can use a generic type as you discovered, but then to get inference you need a helper function. So `const x = test(⋯)` instead of `const x: Test = ⋯`. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPJJYN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Normally that would be perfect. However, in my specific case, I'm transforming the type into a JSON schema (using typescript-json-schema), so that I can use Monaco editor to enable configuring this JSON with proper typings. Now how that library works is that I take a type, and it converts that given type to a schema, so I need to have one single type which I can pass into it. I tried ReturnType<typeof test>, but that doesn't seem to work (I'm not familiar with the inner workings of Typescript, so I have no clue why).

Comment: Okay but that's out of scope for the question as asked. If "there is no specific type that works that way" is the only part of the answer you can use in your use case, that's unfortunate but the way it is.  Is there some way in which my suggested answer would not address your question?

Comment: That's fair, the question does not clearly specify that. Although I did mention that I want to type that object, i.e. how do I get a Type, I did not specify that that single Type has to be generalized to and inferrable for all satisfying objects. You did come up with a nice solution for the given question, so I'll accept that, and then probably ask another one as my problem was not solved. Unless, of course, the statement "There is no specific type that works that way" can be proven.

Comment: "Proven"? What does that mean in the context of TypeScript? It's not like there's a document that lists all things TypeScript *can't* do.  It's a fact that there's no specific type that works the way you're describing. The type needs to know the keys, and if the keys are not fixed then the type has to be generic.  ... wait, *do* you have a specific set of keys, though? Maybe you're looking for [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NV55vw)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't. Any field can be specified, and the existing type has to accommodate for that. By "proving" I meant, that for example, Typescript cannot infer generic types 2 levels deep or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means... TypeScript might be able to "infer generic types 2 levels deep" but the issue is that the type is generic, not specific. I don't know how you expect `Test<T>` to work with your json schema library, or if it's possible. But I guess I'll just answer this question as asked and then worry about it if I see another question appear (or maybe not worry about it if it requires specific library expertise)

Comment: It's not really specific to that library. The question could also be phrased as: Why do I need to specify the IDs in Take #2? Can I somehow help TypeScript so that the very same `x` definition works, only without having to specify the IDs explicitly? I'm interested to see the reasoning on why that utility function works though! Interesting why that works while `ReturnType<typeof test>` does not.

Comment: TS cannot infer generic type arguments in generic *types*, only when calling generic *functions*, which is why I created that utility function. I'll work on an answer and hopefully it will clear some of this stuff up.

Comment: @Tamás What part of `x` (the object) you'd say is the primary source of information? I.e., is `x.fields` built from `x.fieldValues` or vice versa? Try not to answer "both are primary" :)

Comment: `fields` is the primary source. (`fieldValues` could even omit some of the fields if their value is an empty value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `Test` type in TypeScript that works the way you want.  You can write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `Test<K>` where `K` represents the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the keys for a particular object.

But in order for `Test` to be a specific type, you'd basically need to say: "`Test<K>` for *some* `K` I don't care about".  That would require so-called *[existentially quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types)*, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  If those existed in TypeScript you could maybe write `type Test = <exists K> GenericTest<K>` but they don't exist in TypeScript (nor in most other languages, it's not a particular failing of TypeScript) so you can't.  There are ways to encode such types in TypeScript but they amount to a `Promise`-like abstraction and are only useful for some use cases.

So there's no way to write

```
const x: Test = ⋯;
```

directly.  Instead we need to involve generics.

---

Let's look at the generic type `Test<K>`.  Given your description I'd suggest something simpler than your version, without any need to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) or to try to pick apart arrays:

```
type Fields<K extends string> = readonly ({
  type: "string" | "number" | "email"
  id: K
})[]

interface Test<K extends string> {
  fields: Fields<K>
  fieldValues: Record<K, any>
}
```

And then your `x` value would be of type `Test<"field1" | "field2" | "my_field">`. Now, it would be nice if you could just write something like

```
// not valid TS, don't try this
const x: Test<infer> = {⋯}
```

to ask the compiler to infer the generic type argument `K` for you instead of forcing you to write it out.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794) for this, but so far it's not part of the language. Right now generic type arguments can only be inferred when you call a generic *function*.

That implies we can write a little utility helper function `test()` that returns its input, and by calling that function the type argument gets inferred.  So it would look like

```
const x = test({⋯});
```

And then `x` would still have the type `Test<"field1" | "field2" | "my_field">` without requiring you to write that out yourself.  The function is pretty simple:

```
const test = <K extends string>(
  t: Test<K>) => t;
```

That will work because I wrote `Test<K>` in such a way that `K` can easily be inferred from a value of type `Test<K>`.  Let's demonstrate it:

```
const x = test({
  fields: [
    { id: "field1", type: "string" },
    { id: "field2", type: "number" },
    { id: "my_field", type: "email" }
  ],
  fieldValues: {
    field1: "John",
    field2: "John",
    my_field: "@",
  }
});

type X = typeof x;
//   ^? type X = Test<"field1" | "field2" | "my_field">
```

Looks good.  Note that we could use [the TypeScript `typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get a name for the type of `x` without having to write out the type argument.  So the above code shows how you can take an object, have the compiler validate that it matches `Test`, and then get its type.

Well, it only shows that valid objects work. Let's show what happens with invalid objects:

```
const badX1 = test({
  fields: [
    { id: "field1", type: "string" },
    { id: "field2", type: "number" },
    { id: "my_field", type: "email" }
  ],
  fieldValues: { // error!
    //~~~~~~~ <--
    // Property 'field2' is missing
    field1: "John",
    my_field: "@",
  }
});

const badX2 = test({
  fields: [
    { id: "field1", type: "string" },
    { id: "field2", type: "number" },
    { id: "my_field", type: "email" }
  ],
  fieldValues: {
    field1: "John",
    field2: "John",
    field3: "John", // error!
    //~~~~ 
    // Object literal may only specify known properties
    my_field: "@",
  }
});
```

So you get warnings if `fieldValues` has missing or extra keys.

---

That's about as close as you can get. If you really seriously want to hide the generic and make it specific, you can encode an existential generic type.
See [Defining an array of differing generic types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65129070/2887218) and/or [Typescript generics: How to implicitly derive the type of a property of an object from another property of that object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73035641/2887218) for more information on existential generics and their encoding in TypeScript.  It could look like this:

```
type SomeTest = <R>(cb: <K extends string>(t: Test<K>) => R) => R;

const someTest = <K extends string>(t: Test<K>): SomeTest => cb => cb(t);

const someX = someTest({
  fields: [
    { id: "field1", type: "string" },
    { id: "field2", type: "number" },
    { id: "my_field", type: "email" }
  ],
  fieldValues: {
    field1: "John",
    field2: "John",
    my_field: "@",
  }
});
```

So now `someX` is a function that accepts a callback that accepts `Test<K>` for any `K`, and returns the result of that callback.  It's holding onto the same value as `x`, but you can never *directly* access it. You can only touch it through some function for which `K` will be some opaque thing.  You could, for example, index into `fieldValues`:

```
const str = someX(t => t.fields.map(f => t.fieldValues[f.id])).join(":");
console.log(str) // "John:John:@"
```

If you look inside the callback, `f.id` is of type `K` and `t.fieldValues` is of type `Record<K, any>`, for whatever `K` is.  So you're restricted to operations that make sense no matter what `K` is. You'll never be able to access `t.fieldValues.field1`, since that only works when `"field1" extends K` and you don't know that about `K`.

This approach is unlikely to be helpful if you need things to be a JSON-compatible type, since functions are not.  But for future readers with other use cases, it might be a plausible way to do things.  The generic utility function approach is useful in a wide range of use cases. But if the use case requires that there be a single specific object type that represents `Test<K>` for unknown `K`, then this is not possible in TypeScript, until and unless other features are added to the language.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-L2SYHaXSKf0uwNnQ3wxFhoGGYymaOY7G4gpFR0nWU4cjkSoAQnesoAflXqxXegBaOvluUABWLkHIoCgAHJvj8u5Yhho4KhUDFaekSTJyVTuZCjeyZFzsbyHPy2h0LcghT8bdt4jiHQcA9DtR6kd6ZL7qNHma7473z+HpOpI2CY5C4w95+lHynUemMVELFdjyHMCX3e0JwZGdb17aCmXHFAAGZ4P+AtdGLcgyxdStqygJsoAAeS0AArcpukQOAvAKKBjF4LgeFISA-DgbxeAAa0IDgAHdCCgMA210YAEFQd5vxQTlZxXfkBUBKAAGUOA0CANR6dASjGPwtCkPoIkGYZ5DoPhJigDVMnmBh6BKCyrJWddulQJSVK6NTsH6SIhivMYTLM2YHCkRTlNUyyoC0hZQq0YzV1NDpHOUkUmDi5y9xA5Ij1jE8dWTH0nmvcFjyDU8Q1-B4X1BG8CvjcTkBKmR-3RFogKzPY8VzKQIIPKCp0ZWdIJQelupgsTEwXaQlwsaSYocigeiSoVjPC4AADpvlQJbjDAPgJRC5bs3xVAnG8JarBcBwHCWkiOCoPhpAkaRovXDhEAgJbEA4ag+DkeYC2kadCAkP6JC5IA)

Answer (score 1):

As @jcalz pointed out, since one part of the object is validating another part of it, the type of the whole object needs to be inferred, which only can be done (to the best of my knowledge) with functions. We're going to have to use a function that returns whatever it receives, but checks its type along the way – that's going to be the functions sole feature.

```
interface FieldUnknown {
  id: string
  type: string
}

type FieldValues<Fields extends readonly FieldUnknown[]> = {
  [Key in Fields[number]["id"]]: unknown
}

interface TestObject<Fields extends readonly FieldUnknown[]> {
  fields: Fields
  fieldValues: FieldValues<Fields>
}

function createTestObject<const Fields extends readonly FieldUnknown[]>(testObject: TestObject<Fields>): TestObject<Fields> {
  return testObject
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mqoojw).*

Also, you didn't ask for this, but since `fields` looks like a blueprint for an object, there is a possibility of using it as a validation tool:

```
const createFieldsValidator =
  <const Fields extends readonly FieldUnknown[]>(fields: Fields) =>
    (fieldValues: FieldValues<Fields>): TestObject<Fields> =>
      ({ fields, fieldValues });
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mAaaRm).*

---

Further improvements points:

- if you want to **enforce certain types for the properties** of `fieldValues` depending on how `fields` is defined (e.g., if the field is `{ id: "foo", type: "string" }` then `fieldValues.foo` must be a `string`), you're going to have to change `unknown` to something else (relatively complex for this answer):

  ```
  [Key in Fields[number]["id"]]: unknown
  //                             ^^^^^^^
  ```
- if you want to **make all properties of `fieldValues` optional** (regardless of their values), change

  ```
  [Key in Fields[number]["id"]]: unknown
  ```

  … to

  ```
  [Key in Fields[number]["id"]]?: unknown
  //                          ☝️
  ```

Comment: I'm going to write up my own answer since I said I would in the comments. Not sure it's significantly different from this one, though.